# Clone the part of an image that is selected by a Rectangle on an image put in a Canvas in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have my image displayed in a Canvas and I made the height and the width of it according to my Canvas, I can draw (select) rectangles on my image, what I want to do, is to clone the selected part (Rectangle) on my image and display it on my canvas instead of the original image.
is there any less complicated way to do it and clone the right selected part?
here's my XAML code:

```
<Canvas Name="Canvas">
<Image Name="ImgPreview"  MouseDown="img_MouseDown" MouseMove="img_MouseMove" MouseUp="img_MouseUp" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=Canvas}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=Canvas}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
 </Canvas>
```

Comment: First, instead of putting the Image in a Canvas and binding its Width and Height to the ActuaWidth and ActualHeight of the Canvas, it would be much simpler to put it in a Grid (or some other Panel that resizes its children). For your question, use a CroppedBitmap as the Source of the Image control. Take the original Source as the CroppedBitmap's Source.

Comment: I use the Canvas so that I can draw rectangles on the image, I don't know if a Grid would still allow me to do that!